# javascript object problem

Tags: javascript, object

i am a little confused. i want to create a javascript object like:

```
function myObject(){
this.keyOne=1;
this.keyTwo=2;
this.keyThree=3;

function add(){
return this.keyOne+this.keyTwo+this.keyThree;
}

return{
    add: add
}

}
```

so creating this object with

```
var newObject = new myObject();
```

is working fine and all attributes are correct. but with

```
var result = newObject.add;
```

all keys are suddenly undefined! i have no idea why? :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not defining `add()` in a way that's exposed, you could do this for example:

```
function myObject(){
    this.keyOne=1;
    this.keyTwo=2;
    this.keyThree=3;

    this.add = function(){
      return this.keyOne+this.keyTwo+this.keyThree;
    }
}
var newObject = new myObject();
var result = newObject.add();
```

[You can test it here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/wwAeu/).

Also note that you need to call `add()` with parenthesis, since it's a function, or you'll get the function itself back, not the result.

Comment: implementing that way i get a "Result of expression 'myObject.add' [undefined] is not a function.";

Comment: @mkind - do you have it *exactly* as I have it above?  You can see from the demo how this works...your version likely differs from the answer, double check :)

Comment: that the creating and the call happen in another js-file shouldn't be a problem if it is included correctly, right?

Answer (score 3):

There currently is no meaning for the keyword `public` in standard JavaScript.

Based on your original code snippet, I suspect you meant:

```
function myObject(){
    this.keyOne=1;
    this.keyTwo=2;
    this.keyThree=3;

    function add(){
        return this.keyOne+this.keyTwo+this.keyThree;
    }

    return {
        add: add
    };
}
```

The function would then return an object that only has one property: the `add` function. That object is created by the object literal after the `return` keyword.

But then there is no point using `this`. You could have written:

```
function myObject() {

    var keyOne=1;
    var keyTwo=2;
    var keyThree=3;

    function add() {
        return keyOne + keyTwo + keyThree;
    }

    return {
        add: add
    };
}
```

Or even more succinctly:

```
function myObject() {

    var keyOne=1;
    var keyTwo=2;
    var keyThree=3;

    return {
        add: function() {
            return keyOne + keyTwo + keyThree;
        }
    };
}
```

This has the added advantage that you don't need to call it prefixed with `new`. It's just an ordinary function that creates and returns an object which contains another function:

```
var o = myObject();
alert(o.add());
```

You could allow the caller to specify the numbers to be added, like this:

```
function myObject(keyOne, keyTwo, keyThree) {

    return {
        add: function() {
            return keyOne + keyTwo + keyThree;
        }
    };
}

var o = myObject(5, 4, 7);
alert(o.add());
```

Comment: thanks.. the "public" is just a misspelling. i changed it above